# How to add a new value to the map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am working on the React app, and there I have an array `shopsAsArray`. This array looks like this:

```
[
    {
       "shopName":"Billa",
       "ID":"01",
       "ratings":[
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Good assortiment."
          },
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Very Tasty Food!"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "shopName":"Albert",
       "ID":"02",
       "ratings":[
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Nice"
          },
          {
             "stars":4,
             "comment":"Not bad"
          }
       ]
    }
]
```

I need to add a new comment to one of these shops. This shop is the same as variable `chosenShop`.
So my task is to add a new comment to the shop that has the same `ID` as `chosenShop`.
I know that the next function is wrong, but I don’t know how to fix it:

```
shopsAsArray.get(chosenShop.ID).push(newComment);
```

Comment: `shopsAsArray.find(shop => shop.id === chosenShop.ID).ratings.push(newComment);`

Comment: Maybe shopsAsArray.find(shop => shop.id === chosenShop.ID).ratings.comment.push(newComment)  would be better, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: OK, it was supposed to be `shop.ID` (capitals) my bad there but [it seems to work](https://jsbin.com/pipoqig/edit?js,console). If it doesn't, then there is not enough information in the question to know what's wrong. I assumed that `chosenShop.ID` is valid.

Comment: Can you advise me, please, what should I do, in the case when I have the next hook:
const [shopsAsArray, setShopsAsArray] = useState(Object.keys (shopsInfo).map((pid) => shopsInfo[pid]));

If I try this: let newRating={stars: newReview, comment: newComment}; 
 setShopsAsArray (shopsAsArray.find(shop => shop.ID === chosenShop.ID).ratings.push(newRating));
It doesn’t work

Comment: If you are using react (your original question wasn't tagged with "react") and `shopsAsArray` is in react state, don't use `push` i.e. don't modify (mutate) the original state data. Instead, create a new copy and store that in state.